# How can I get all of fields with meteor and mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Here is what `Users.find({_id: userId})` looks like on `Users` collection

```
{
  "_id" : "123sdasdasd",
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-15T20:36:01.549+0000"),
  "roles" : {
      "internal" : [
          "admin",
          "maneger"
      ],
      "client" : [
          "admin",
          "maneger",
          "normal-user",
      ],
      "other" : [
          "admin",
          "maneger",
          "normal-user",
          "manage"
      ],
  },
  "username" : "sample@gmail.com"
}
```

And what I like to do is get all of the fields? on `roles`

so `internal`, `client` and `other`. I'd like to have them in an array `['internal', 'client', 'other']` like this.

`const boardNames = ['internal', 'client', 'other']`

I'm trying to do this on `client side` but if it's easier I can do on `server side` as well.

Can I do it?

Comment: const boardNames = Object.keys(user.roles)

Comment: If you need also iterate over each kind of roles, you can use also "for of" syntax. for(const kind of roles) { console.log(kind); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both Ricardo and Klaucode are correct.

const boardNames = Object.keys(user.roles)

If you need also iterate over each kind of roles, you can use also "for of" syntax. for(const kind of roles) { console.log(kind); }